# Use of the nominative versus the instrumental to convey permanent state

Tags: творительный-падеж

In "A Comprehensive Russian Grammar", Wade states that in the past tense, the nominative case is used to indicate a permanent state, e.g.

> "По профессии он был ботаник"
>
> "By profession he was a botanist."

. . .while the instrumental case is chiefly used for temporary states, e.g.

> "Во время войны я был офицером."
>
> "During the war I was an officer."

But then proceeds to state that the instrumental case may also be used to denote permanent past states e.g.

> "Она была сестрой Полевого"
>
> "She was Polevoi's sister."

The explanation following this suggests that where you have two nouns (or noun and pronoun) linked by a form of 'to be', the more specific is nominative, the more general is instrumental. However, the reason I was looking this up was because I encountered a question sentence that read "Кем был Фома́?" where it seems like we're dealing with just one noun (Фома́) and the instrumental case is being applied to a question word, but also that this is about 'permanent state.'

When, in such a situation, would the instrumental be used and when--if ever--would the nominative be used?